# circular references among javascript functions

Tags: javascript

How can one define a pair of functions that call each other in Javascript so that JS-lint does not complain that 'factorial' is being used before it is defined?

```
function factorial1(n) { return factorial(n); }
function factorial(n) { return n === 0 ? 1 : n * factorial1(n - 1); }
```

It seems there is no valid ordering that will satisfy JSlint. 
(One can be embedded in the other, but this would be a nightmare for a collection of functions that all call each other).

Surely this is handled by the language right?
Is this just a bug in JSlint?
(This question must have been answered somewhere, but I cannot find it!)

Comment: You probably meant `n === 0 ? 1 : ...`. Also, what doesn't work (except the logical error I already pointed out)?

Comment: >>Surely this is handled by the language right? 
Generally after sometime your page becomes unresponsive and the browser throws up a popup alert asking you to either stop the script or let it continue.

Comment: @dobert yes, your edit is correct.  but the real issue is that JSlint complains that 'factorial' is being reference before it is defined.

Comment: there is one simple solution: use [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/) instead ;)

Comment: Have you a real example where this kind of design is actually pertinent ? in the example you wrote, you can remove entirely the factorial1 function...

Comment: @basilikum Hah! well I am new to Javascript, so I thought JSlint would be a stern but useful teacher.  Or would you recommend the new guy ignoring JSlint in favor of JShint?

Comment: @benzonico  yes I am writing an evaluator where many of the methods recursively call multiple others within the "class"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The references inside the functions is not resolved until they are executed. As long as both functions has been defined by the time one of them executes, they will find each other.

If you want to get rid of the JSLint warning, you could define the name of the function, just before:

```
var factorial;
function factorial1(n) { return factorial(n); }
function factorial(n) { return n === 0 ? 1 : n * factorial1(n - 1); }
```

Comment: Sorry I did not clarify that the issue is that JS-lint is complaining.

Comment: Thanks!  of course.  I did not consider mixing in a var function with the named functions!

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this syntax to functions:

```
var factorial1 = function(n) { return factorial(n); }
var factorial = function(n) { return n === 0 ? 1 : n * factorial1(n - 1); }
```

Will not be able to forget to "declare" function with this syntax.

Comment: All statements should be terminated with semicolons. Not a huge deal here, but it could cause problems if you copy-pasted these statements around.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to this problem, is to pass it as a callback function, like this:

```
const factorial1 = (n, callback) => { return callback(n); }
const factorial = (n) => { return n === 0 ? 1 : n * factorial1(n - 1, factorial ); }
```